# Number of stereoisomers of trisubstituted cyclopentane

Tags: stereochemistry

When 4-methylcyclopent-1-ene reacts with bromine, then 1,2-dibromo-4-methylcyclopentane forms. And I am stuck on determining the amount of stereoisomers that can form as a result.

[image: 4-methylcyclopent-1-ene]

1,2-dibromo-4-methylcyclopentane has two chiral carbon atoms, those of bromine. And an internal mirror plane, we should have 3 optical isomers.

But I am confused upon drawing the following:
[image: stereoisomers of 1,2-dibromo-4-methylcyclopentane]

1 and 4 appear to be the same, 2 and 3 appear to be the same.

5 and 7 appear to be the same, 6 and 8 appear to be the same.

This gives me 4 isomers. So I draw them different again:

[image: stereoisomers of puckered 1,2-dibromo-4-methylcyclopentane]

The puckered structure leaves me doubting myself: while I think that the internal mirror plane causes there to be only 2 different cis structures instead of 4 (or instead of 1 if it had been 1,2-dibromo-4,4-dimethylcyclopentane), I am not sure if the trans structures are actually the same.

Comment: So propene or pentene?

Comment: In either case there's only 4 isomers, because of plane of symmetry.

Comment: Thank you Mithoron for your comments: pentene is what I meant, I've edited my question. I will also attempt to upload pictures of what I exactly mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost everything that needs to be said has been said. But I do have a few comments about configurations. In enantiomeric, trans-dibromides **1** and **2**, the methyl groups are chirotopic and non-stereogenic. Inversion of the stereochemistry of the methyl group in either **1** or **2** returns the same structure, respectively. Thus, there is no designation for stereochemistry at the C<sub>4</sub> methyl center. On the other hand, inversion of the stereochemistry of the methyl group in **3** gives **4** and the same operation on **4** produces **3**. Therefore, the methyl center in achiral isomers **3** and **4** is achirotopic and stereogenic. Accordingly, the C<sub>4</sub> centers have lowercase descriptors, r and s, respectively. This [site](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/RSrs.html) might be of help.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this info, really informative and contains the terminology and information I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Nice pictures and analysis!

There are four different stereoisomers: one pair of enantiomers (the trans structures) and two achiral isomers (the cis structures).

In a mixture of all four, there will be 3 sets of boiling points, peaks in chromatographic separation (with achiral columns), etc.

> 1,2-dibromo-4-methylcyclopentane has two chiral carbon atoms, those of bromine. And an internal mirror plane, we should have 3 optical isomers.

This argument works only if both bromine-bound carbons are (R), or both are (S). Otherwise, the methyl-bound carbon has two different substituents, and could be counted as chiral as well.